# vue-cli-service serve and buid generating different styles

Tags: javascript, vue-cli

I'm not sure how to show it but for some reason after `vue-cli-service build` and `vue-cli-service serve` page looks different. In the case of `build` all is fine but in the case of `serve` styles are messed, but there are no errors while building and no error in the browser console. I can share the `package.json` if it can help and some other configuration files I have...

package.json

```
{
  "name": "newlanding",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "vue": "^2.6.11",
    "vuelidate": "^0.7.5",
    "vuetify": "^2.2.11"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@mdi/js": "^5.4.55",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.4.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.4.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.4.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "eslint": "^6.7.2",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^6.2.2",
    "sass": "^1.19.0",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.0",
    "vue-cli-plugin-vuetify": "~2.0.7",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11",
    "vuetify-loader": "^1.3.0"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/essential",
      "eslint:recommended"
    ],
    "parserOptions": {
      "parser": "babel-eslint"
    },
    "rules": {}
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not dead"
  ]
}
```

vue.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  "transpileDependencies": [
    "vuetify"
  ]
}
```

babel.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    '@vue/cli-plugin-babel/preset'
  ]
}
```

I know it's hard to find the reason without the actuall code... but maybe you have some suggestion, I do not know where else to look, as I told before no errors while building and in browser, also no errors in yarn-error.log.

Comment: Same problem here, did you find a solution? I'd appreciate some help since I'm facing the same issue.

Comment: partially by adding `scoped` to the style tag.

Comment: You won't see any errors here - the issue is there are CSS conflicts (same selectors or class names but different styles in different components). You will have to manually inspect in DevTools each element with "broken" style to see which CSS rules exactly are getting overriden by other rules.